# Bitmap generator paired with an neural network image recogniser?

Tags: neural-network

I'm new to programming, and i would be great if someone could point me in the right direction.

Hoping to create this project, but not sure whether to try and complete the programming myself or maybe pay someone to create it for me.

Hoping to create a bitmap generator that creates small (300x300px ish) images (similar to this ... RANDOM.ORG - Bitmap Generator ), which then feeds these to an neural network based image recogniser, which has been trained to pick out particular images it thinks matches an initial set of black&white bitmap images I give it to learn.

Basically, I'd like to create a program that I can feed a set of images, and it then generates images based on these, with similar tones, patterns and shapes..

Before I even start thinking about making this, do you reckon it would even work? The generator would have to be pretty quick for the image recogniser to have any hope of finding anything. And I'd have to be able to skew the percentage of black/white bytes in order to come up with the sort of images I feed it to learn.

If anyone could offer any suggests on where to start, that would be amazing!

Comment: It has been attempted to feed images from genetic algorithm to a facial recognition software as fitness the fitness function for the GA. The results were impressive (read: a low-res but very clear generic human face on a uniform-noise background).

Comment: Look at http://i.ytimg.com/vi/qS5HWBNvf9U/0.jpg

Comment: That is exactly the sort of thing I had in mind, thanks Jan.